# how to set width of style to match outer DIV

Tags: html, css, asp.net, list

Using JQuery tabs, I have 2 tabs inside my div, `Info & Images`

Contents of `<ul>` contains the 2 tabs, ul is coloured blue. but the `OnCLickk="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn_Click"`  returns a table.

If the contents of the table is wider than the updatePanel width(300), the scroll bar appears and allows the user to view the rest of the table, adjusting the width of the update panel, thus not showing blue for the remainder of the ul.

So iv tried setting the width of the ul to 100% which I though would fill the outer div...didnt work..any ideas?

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel8" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="true"
           Style="position: relative; overflow: hidden; background-color: White;               
          width: 300px; height: 300px; margin: 5px; text-align: center; outline-style: none; overflow-y: hidden; overflow-x:hidden;">
           <%--width: 500px; height: 450px; --%>

           <ContentTemplate>
                   <div id="DivHolding2Tabs" class="overflowcontent" style="border-color:Black;border-width:1px;border-style:solid;">

                       <ul id="tabList" style="width:inherit;">
                           <li><a href="#tabs-1">Info</a> </li>
                           <li><a href="#tabs-2" style="display:none;">Images</a> </li>

                       </ul>

                       <div id="tabs-1" class="WorkFlowLayout">
                               <b><font color="FF6600">Feature Properties </font></b>
                                <div id="divFeatureInfo" runat="server">
                                </div>
                       </div>

                       <div id="tabs-2" class="WorkFlowLayout">
                                <b><font color="FF6600">Images</font></b>
                                <div id="ImagesRelatingToFeatureDIV" runat="server">  
                               </div>
                       </div>
                   </div>
                   <br />
                   <br />
                   <div class="buttonwrap">
                       <span id="Span5" class="ActionBtns">
                           <asp:Button ID="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn" runat="server" Style="display: none;
                               visibility: hidden;" OnClick="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn_Click" />
                       </span>
                   </div>
           </ContentTemplate>
           <Triggers>
               <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ViewFeatureWorkflowImagePostBackBtn" EventName="Click" />
           </Triggers>
       </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Adding a link to the work will be of great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional wrap `div` inside your `.overflowcontent`. Tab `div` and `.overflowcontent` should not be the same.

```
<div class="overflowcontent">
    <div id="DivHolding2Tabs">
        <!-- tabs -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the ul is the only problem. Try this.

```
ul, .WorkFlowLayout, .overflowcontent {
   width: 100%!important;
}
```